# In buffer overflow return address is overwritten with incorrect address but it still works

Tags: c, assembly, stack, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to make buffer overflow and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int check_authentication(char *password) {

   char password_buffer[16];
   int auth_flag = 0;
   strcpy(password_buffer, password);
   if(strcmp(password_buffer, "brillig") == 0)
     auth_flag = 1;
   if(strcmp(password_buffer, "outgrabe") == 0)
     auth_flag = 1;

   return auth_flag; 

}




int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   if(argc < 2) {
      printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
    }
    if(check_authentication(argv[1])) {
      printf("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
      printf(" Access Granted.\n");
      printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
    } 

    else {
      printf("\nAccess Denied.\n");
    }
}
```

The provided password from command line will be compared to "brilling" and "outgrabe" if user input matches any of these, access will be granted, if not it will be denied. As I know if provided password will be greater than 16 return address will be overwritten but  when I input "A" 17 it is not overwritten. Instead of that auth_flag is overwritten and is 65(0x41 in hex which is A). I can't figure out why the variable is overwritten instead of return address. I'm compiling with this

> gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -g -o test test.c

Hope you guys can help. Thanks.

Comment: The C-compiler is free to assume that no undefined behavior ever occurs during your program's execution. It is also allowed to arbitrarily reorder the addresses of your local variables, provided this does not change the execution of a well-defined program.

Comment: So you mean that compiler could assume that auth_flag should be created first and then the buffer and thats the reason it overwrites the auth_flag?

Comment: You could just use [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) instead to avoid your issue.

Comment: @Misery from OP's question, I gather that buffer overflow is not an *issue*, but rather a desired outcome.

Comment: @dureuill I didn't saw it that way, my bad then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sourav Ghosh said, your program invokes undefined behavior.

In practice, this means you need to dive into the generated code to see how the stack is used.

As this relies heavily on your environment (machine, OS, compiler version, etc.), there is little we can do to debug it for you.
In **my** environment, the `authenticated` flag is stored at ebp-12, while the buffer is stored at ebp-28. ebp-28 is passed to strcmp, meaning that overflow will result in `authenticated` being overwritten.
A longer string will eventually smash the return address : "1234567890123456000000000000" triggers a segfault in my place.

A recommended starting point could be compiling to assembly:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -g -S test.c
```

generates test.s which will show you how your stack look.
You can also look at the binary using de-assemblers (`objdump` and `ida pro` come to mind), if compiling from source is not a facility you can afford ;-).

**EDIT:** From your pastebin, here is what I gather:

There clearly appears to be some form of stack protection:

```
 movl    %gs:20, %eax
 [...]
 movl    -12(%ebp), %edx
 xorl    %gs:20, %edx
 je      .L5
 call    __stack_chk_fail
```

The `__stack_chk_fail` is called if the place at -12(%ebp) is not %gs:20 anymore (eg your stack has been corrupted).

As a side note, if a real attacker who wants to bypass authentication can control the value of your "authenticated" flag, they won't even bother to try and erase the return address for the beauty of it.

Comment: You should use the same arguments as you did originally. In particular, this code has stack protector enabled.

Comment: Edited my gcc invocation to reflect OP's flags. In case of doubt, use `objdump`

Comment: can you tell me how to disable it?

Comment: oh.. know i get it thank you. but can you explain how is it possible to control the flag without erasing return address? If its not the way they will put multiple A's as input :)

Comment: The layout or your stack is more or less the following: buffer[16];  authenticated; *other_stuff*; return address. Therefore a buffer overflow will overwrite the authenticated flag before anything else

Answer (score 0):

Once the input (`password`) string contains more than `15` (not `16`, need terminating null) charcater, using `strcpy()` will invoke  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

- Before that (unless that happens), your program is fine.
- After that happens, you cannot predict *anything*.

So, after your program shows UB, you cannot expect it to behave in a desired way. It can do anything and everyting expected or unexpected. Whether it *overwrites* `auth_flag` or not, cannot be determined.

Maybe, it's worthy to mention that the allocation of memory for variables does not necessarily take place in any particular order (of appearance). Your compiler is free to allocate memory in any order it sees fit.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to use strcpy() function and overwrite the return address?

Comment: @Ojs what do you mean exactly by `overwrite the return address`?

Comment: Well, you can't predict anything in a general case, if you sit with a debugger and craft a specific string to use with a specific binary, you can predict what will happen in a great many cases.  If that weren't true buffer overflow attacks would not work

Comment: in "overwrite the return address" I mean change the $ebp+4 address in check_authentication function

Comment: Just use a longer string. It will eventually hit the return address ;) Note that there may be other things on the stack such as a frame pointer or saved registers.